# Testing standard output by substituting stdout

Tags: rust

My goal is to test the output of a function that goes to the standard output. So far, my best attempt is to substitute the stream with a string in the tests.

This is what I managed to achieve so far:

```
use std::io;
use std::fmt;

fn hello(stdout: &mut std::fmt::Write) {
    writeln!(stdout, "Hello world");
}

#[test]
fn hello_test() {
    let mut stdout = String::new();

    // pass fake stdout when calling when testing
    hello(&mut stdout);

    assert_eq!(stdout, "Hello world\n".to_string());
}

fn main() {
    // pass real stdout when calling from main

    hello(&mut io::stdout());
}
```

The tests work, but unfortunately `io::stdout()` does not implement the `fmt::Write` trait.

What is the best solution for testing a function that writes to the standard output in Rust? Is there a way to fix my solution with strings, or should I look for an alternative?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.write.html) macro expects the destination operand to implement *either* [`std::fmt::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Write.html) or [`std::io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html). Since [`writeln!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.writeln.html) delegates to `write!`, this also applies to `writeln!`.

The documentation for `std::fmt::Write` says this:

> the `io::Write` trait is favored over implementing this trait

Since [`Stdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdout.html) implements `std::io::Write`, you should change the bounds on your code from `fmt::Write` to `io::Write`. Note, however, that `String` doesn't implement `io::Write`, since `io::Write` accepts arbitrary bytes that may not be well-formed UTF-8; you can use `Vec<u8>` instead.

```
use std::io;

fn hello(stdout: &mut io::Write) {
    writeln!(stdout, "Hello world");
}

#[test]
fn hello_test() {
    let mut stdout = Vec::new();

    // pass fake stdout when calling when testing
    hello(&mut stdout);

    assert_eq!(stdout, b"Hello world\n");
}

fn main() {
    // pass real stdout when calling from main

    hello(&mut io::stdout());
}
```

For improved performance, if only one threads need to write on stdout, consider passing a [`StdoutLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.StdoutLock.html) rather than a `Stdout` to your function (with `Stdout`, each write acquires and releases a lock).

---

If you really prefer to use `std::fmt::Write` instead, then you could use an adapter struct that converts `fmt::Write` calls to `io::Write` calls.

```
use std::io;
use std::fmt;

struct WriteAdapter<W>(W);

impl<W> fmt::Write for WriteAdapter<W>
where
    W: io::Write,
{
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        self.0.write_all(s.as_bytes()).map_err(|_| fmt::Error)
    }

    fn write_fmt(&mut self, args: fmt::Arguments) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        self.0.write_fmt(args).map_err(|_| fmt::Error)
    }
}

fn hello(stdout: &mut fmt::Write) {
    writeln!(stdout, "Hello world");
}

#[test]
fn hello_test() {
    let mut stdout = String::new();

    // pass fake stdout when calling when testing
    hello(&mut stdout);

    assert_eq!(stdout, "Hello world\n");
}

fn main() {
    // pass real stdout when calling from main

    hello(&mut WriteAdapter(io::stdout()));
}
```

Comment: Actually `write!` only needs a `write_fmt` method in scope, which is *usually* provided by `std::io::Write` or `std::fmt::Write`, but it doesn't need to be that way.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Francis. Works great.

Comment: For future readers, the liner `fn hello(stdout: &mut io::Write) {` is usually written as `fn hello<W: Write>(stdout: W) {` for monomorphization (which is usually what you want).